# CIR MODEL Log-likelihood estimation of Initial Parameters

Tags: matlab

for this

```
% Optimization using fminsearch
if ~isfield(Model, 'MatlabDisp'), Model.MatlabDisp = 'off'; end;

options = optimset('LargeScale', 'off', 'MaxIter', 300, 'MaxFunEvals',300,'Display',Model.MatlabDisp, 'TolFun', 1e-4, 'TolX', 1e-4, 'TolCon', 1e-4); 
if ~isfield(Model, 'Method'), Model.Method = 'besseli'; end;
if strcmp(Model.Method, 'ncx2pdf')
    [Params, Fval, Exitflag] =  fminsearch(@(Params) CIRobjective2(Params, Model), InitialParams, options);   
else
    [Params, Fval, Exitflag] =  fminsearch(@(Params) CIRobjective1(Params, Model), InitialParams, options);   
end
%tol = 1e-6;
%lb = [ tol,  tol, tol];
%ub = [ inf,  inf, inf];    
%[Params, Fval, Exitflag] = fmincon(@(Params) CIRobjective1(Params, Model),                                                                  
InitialParams, [], [], [], [], lb, ub, [], options);

Results.Params = Params;
Results.Fval = -Fval/Nobs;
Results.Exitflag = Exitflag;

if strcmp(Model.Disp, 'y')
    fprintf('\n alpha = %+3.6f\n mu    = %+3.6f\n sigma = %+3.6f\n', Params(1), Params(2), Params(3));
    fprintf(' log-likelihood = %+3.6f\n', -Fval/Nobs);
end
```

I have got

Undefined function or method 'mtimes' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

```
Error in ==> CIRobjective2 at 26
u = c*exp(-alpha*TimeStep)*DataL;

Error in ==> @(Params)CIRobjective2(Params,Model)


Error in ==> fminsearch at 205
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});
```

This is the actual source file

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37297-maximum-likelihood-estimation-of-the-cox-ingersoll-ross-process-the-matlab-implementation/content/CIRestimation.m

Could you please help me why I get these errors?

Regards,
Masoud

Answer (score 0):

you sure you put all your function right and define it well?
it maybe your function is not in right path.

try to do initial parameter first, define InitialParams so it comes out in your variables. Then do CIRobjective1 then 2 then yo can do the optimization using fminsearch. Hope that helps. I'm a new user of matlab, but got to use it for my theses.

Regards, Lita.